# override func invalidateIntrinsicContentSize() gives does not override error. Removing override gives conflicting with superclass error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am using Apple Tutorial "Start Developing iOS Apps (Swift) - implement a custom control, with Xcode 8 and Swift 3. I am doing "Declare a Constant for the Button Size" section but getting an error. Apple suggests that we use the following code.

```
override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {  
  let buttonSize = Int(frame.size.height)  
  let width = (buttonSize * starCount) + (spacing * (starCount - 1))  

  return CGSize(width: width, height: buttonSize)  
}
```

But, the first error (which is sort of irrelevant to this question) is that in Swift 3, intrinsicContentSize() has been changed to invalidateIntrinsicContentSize(). After using override func invalidateIntrinsicContentSize() I get the following error.

```
swift:53:19: Method does not override any method from its superclass
```

When I remove override, I get the following error.

```
53:10: Method 'invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()' with Objective-C selector 
'invalidateIntrinsicContentSize' conflicts with method
'invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()' from superclass 'UIView' with the 
same Objective-C selector
```

Can anyone please explain what might be going wrong? What can I change or add to get rid of this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In Swift3, it has been changed to a property and its not available to you as a method. You should override the getter to return your desired size:

```
override public var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
     return CGSize()//your desired size here
}
```

Please refer to the documents [IntrinsicContentSize](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622600-intrinsiccontentsize)

Answer (score 0):

In swift intrinsicContentSize has change to stored property, not invalidateIntrinsicContentSize(), so you should try to override `var intrinsicContentSize`.